# post without saving Django Rest

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am developing a bot chat in python, but I have a question when sending message to the API, I need to make a post without saving the registry, would have to send the content handle and return a message, is it possible to accomplish this with serializer?

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class SpeechSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   speech = serializers.CharField()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from botpaf.serializers import SpeechSerializer


@api_view(['POST','GET'])

def speech_list(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      serializer = SpeechSerializer(data=request.data)
      return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is possible. Just need to keep one thing in mind when deserializing data explicitly need to call `serializer.is_valid()` to get validated data.

Reference [Link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)